# Identity Server 4 and ASP.NET Web Forms Client - invalid grant type

Tags: c#, webforms, identityserver4

I have setup Identity Server 4 locally and added an MVC Net Core client with no problems.

I cannot get my .Net Framework Web Forms app to work though.

When I try to hit the About (Secure page) .aspx page I get the below error:

"Sorry, there was an error : unauthorized_client
Invalid grant type for client"

I have tried all the various Granttypes without success.

I feel like my Client setup in ID4 is incorrect. Various blog posts say I should use the Code grant but then others say use id_token.

I have setup the Client as follows in  the ID4 server app:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "aspx",
    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,                

    //My web forms aspx client
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5969/" },

    //My web forms aspx client
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5969/" },

    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

    RequirePkce = false,

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile                    
    },
}
```

Startup.cs in my Web Forms App (I am using the \WebFormsClient\ sample from https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/WebFormsClient/Startup.cs)

I am a little confused as to what https://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo is supposed to be - I get a 401.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            SlidingExpiration = true
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
      
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {                
            AuthenticationType = "oidc",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",                
            Authority = "https://localhost:5001/",
            ClientId = "aspx",
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:5969/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5969/",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile email",
            UseTokenLifetime = false,
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                {
                    var claims_to_exclude = new[]
                    {
                        "aud", "iss", "nbf", "exp", "nonce", "iat", "at_hash"
                    };

                    var claims_to_keep =
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                        .Where(x => false == claims_to_exclude.Contains(x.Type)).ToList();
                    claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken != null)
                    {
                        claims_to_keep.Add(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(new Uri("https://localhost:5001/connect/userinfo"), n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                        var userInfoClaims = userInfoResponse.Claims
                            .Where(x => x.Item1 != "sub") // filter sub since we're already getting it from id_token
                            .Select(x => new Claim(x.Item1, x.Item2));
                        claims_to_keep.AddRange(userInfoClaims);
                    }

                    var ci = new ClaimsIdentity(
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                        "name", "role");
                    ci.AddClaims(claims_to_keep);

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationTicket(
                        ci, n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties
                    );
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                    {
                        var id_token = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token")?.Value;
                        n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = id_token;
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
    }
}
```

Comment: "id_token token" is Implicit flow, so you need to include that in your `AllowedGrantTypes`.

Comment: Also useful is turn on and observe trace-level logging on the identity server; it lays out in plenty of detail exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Excellent - works! I set AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit and removed "email" from web forms Scope

Comment: Great - I'll add an answer; feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"id_token token" is [Implicit flow](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/OpenID-Connect-Flows), so you need to include that in your `AllowedGrantTypes`.

Re the [UserInfo](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/userinfo.html) [endpoint](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo), it just returns claims about the user, based on the access token you call it with.  Getting a 401 response probably means you aren't passing a valid access token.  It can be useful if you need additional user claims and you only have an access token but not an ID token.